# Speed up WCF client instantiation?

Tags: vb.net, wcf, wcf-client, channelfactory, wcf-proxy

Suppose my WCF client interface is called `ISDK`, and the client object itself is called `ISDKClient`, as generated by `svcutil`.

When I instantiate a WCF client like this:

```
Dim myClient As New ISDKClient
```

it takes around 1.5sec to create the first client, then ~300ms subsequently.

If I use a channel factory approach:

```
Dim myChannelFactory As New ChannelFactory(Of ISDK)(binding, endpoint)
Dim myChannel As ISDK = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel()
```

Takes 1.5sec for the first call, but subsequent calls to `CreateChannel` are near instant. The problem is that method signatures in `ISDK` are different from those listed under `ISDKClient`. `ISDK` has request/response pattern, while `ISDKClient` has normal methods with parameters.

Can I control how `svcutil` generates a proxy file, to avoid request/response method signature pattern in the interface? [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), method signatures should match, i.e. client should directly reference its interface for all calls (but it's not my case):

```
Public Function SampleMethod(ByVal msg As String) As String _
                                           Implements ISampleService.SampleMethod
  Return MyBase.Channel.SampleMethod(msg)
End Function
```

If not, is it possible to instantiate a WCF client based using an already existing channel? Something like:

```
Dim myClient As New ISDKClient(myChannel)
```

If not, is there any other way to improve performance of instantiating new WCF clients in my application? Assuming all that's available is a WCF service over HTTP.

Comment: Find out where the time is being spent.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Creating metadata for a channel, obviously.

Comment: "Obviously", and, during what part of creating a channel? Is it blocked on network I/O? To where? "Obviously", it's network I/O to the service. But what if it's not?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Channel factory and the client should be using the same way of accessing the resource. The only difference is that the [heavy lifting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh314046(v=vs.110).aspx) is done once. There is no network I/O going on to create a client or channel from a factory. I tested with no access to the WCF service, everything still runs, with numbers being the same. If I profile, it says "not my code" is where time is being spent, specifically the `clr.dll`.